# Cannot read property 'password' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm making a little database using mongodb and nodejs, I want to Update a field but I have this error, the code is, the name of the model is "ListaSalas":

```
router.post('/updatesala', function(peticion, responsep){
  var password = peticion.body.password;
  var url = peticion.body.url;

  ListaSalas.findOne({'url': url}, function (err, respuesta) {
    var PassBusca = respuesta.password;
    if(PassBusca){
      responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      responsep.write("passwordmal");
      responsep.end();
    }else{
      ListaSalas.update({url: url}, {password: password});
      responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      responsep.write("passwordok");
      responsep.end();
    }
  });
```

Does anybody know where my mistake is please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the result returned from the **[`findOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne)** method, if there is no match then `respuesta` is null hence the error

> Cannot read property 'password' of null

To get around this, use the **[`updateOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#updateOne)** method directly and in the callback check whether the document has been modified:

```
router.post('/updatesala', function(peticion, responsep){
    var password = peticion.body.password;
    var url = peticion.body.url;

    ListaSalas.updateOne({'url': url}, {'password': password}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return err;
        var PassBusca = result.result.n;
        var pwd = PassBusca ? "passwordmal": "passwordok";
        responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        responsep.write(pwd);
        responsep.end();        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if there is an error or not.

```
router.post('/updatesala', function(peticion, responsep){
  var password = peticion.body.password;
  var url = peticion.body.url;

  ListaSalas.findOne({'url': url}, function (err, respuesta) {
    if (err) return err;
    var PassBusca = respuesta.password;
    if(PassBusca){
      responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      responsep.write("passwordmal");
      responsep.end();
    }else{
      ListaSalas.update({url: url}, {password: password});
      responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      responsep.write("passwordok");
      responsep.end();
    }
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Afaik, this code will never respond to the client in case of error.

Comment: @xersiee was more just pointing out that you should check for an error. It is up to OP how it responds to the client!

Answer (score 1):

After checking the answers I could change the code, thanks to chridam's idea I used the method directly, instead of updateOne() it was update(), and in the database I put a default value in the password field ("password"), at the end the code is:

```
router.post('/updatesala', function(peticion, responsep){
  var password = peticion.body.password;
  var url = peticion.body.url;
  ListaSalas.findOne({'url': url}, function (err, respuesta) {
  var compara = respuesta.password;
  if (compara=="password"){
    ListaSalas.update({'url': url}, {'password': password},function (err, result) {
        if (err) return err;
        });
    responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    responsep.write('passwordok');
    responsep.end();
  }else{
    responsep.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    responsep.write('passwordmal');
    responsep.end();}
  });
});
```